# Merging records in a table with 2-columns primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I have prepared a simple test case for my question -

In a game player ids and names are stored in the table `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

And the players can rate each other in the table `reviews` with 2-columns PK:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
        uid integer NOT NULL CHECK (uid <> author) REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
        author integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        review varchar(255),
        PRIMARY KEY(uid, author)
);
```

Here both tables are filled with sample data:

```
INSERT INTO users (uid, name) VALUES (1, 'User 1');
INSERT INTO users (uid, name) VALUES (2, 'User 2');
INSERT INTO users (uid, name) VALUES (3, 'User 3');
INSERT INTO users (uid, name) VALUES (4, 'User 4');

INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (1, 2, 'User 2 says: 1 is nice');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (1, 3, 'User 3 says: 1 is nice');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (1, 4, 'User 4 says: 1 is nice');

INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (2, 1, 'User 1 says: 2 is nice');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (2, 3, 'User 3 says: 2 is nice');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (2, 4, 'User 4 says: 2 is ugly');

INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (3, 1, 'User 1 says: 3 is nice');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (3, 2, 'User 2 says: 3 is ugly');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (3, 4, 'User 4 says: 3 is ugly');

INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (4, 1, 'User 1 says: 4 is ugly');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (4, 2, 'User 2 says: 4 is ugly');
INSERT INTO reviews (uid, author, review) VALUES (4, 3, 'User 3 says: 4 is ugly');
```

When my mobile app notices, that the same player is using several user ids, it merges the records with the custom stored function shown below.

While merging (to the `out_uid`) the user reviews of himself are deleted and any resulting overlapping reviews should be dropped too.

*(To the background of merging records: this is really necessary, because I run another game with player reviews for many years, and users kept pestering me - why their reviews and game stats are different, when they logged in via Facebook, via Google+, via Apple Game Center...)*

Since there is no `UPDATE ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` - I have tried to help myself with the following two [INSERT ... SELECT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html) in the custom stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_users(
                in_uids integer[],
                OUT out_uid integer
        ) RETURNS integer AS
$func$
BEGIN
        SELECT
                MIN(uid)
        INTO STRICT
                out_uid 
        FROM users
        WHERE uid = ANY(in_uids);

        -- delete self-reviews
        DELETE FROM reviews
        WHERE uid = out_uid
        AND author = ANY(in_uids);

        DELETE FROM reviews
        WHERE author = out_uid
        AND uid = ANY(in_uids);

        -- try to copy as many reviews OF this user as possible
        INSERT INTO reviews (
                uid,
                author,
                review
        ) SELECT
                out_uid,        -- change to out_uid
                author,
                review
        FROM reviews
        WHERE uid <> out_uid
        AND uid = ANY(in_uids)
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

        DELETE FROM reviews
        WHERE uid <> out_uid
        AND uid = ANY(in_uids);

        -- try to copy as many reviews BY this user as possible
        INSERT INTO reviews (
                uid,
                author,
                review
        ) SELECT
                uid,
                out_uid,        -- change to out_uid
                review
        FROM reviews
        WHERE author <> out_uid
        AND author = ANY(in_uids)
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

        DELETE FROM reviews
        WHERE author <> out_uid
        AND author = ANY(in_uids);

        DELETE FROM users
        WHERE uid <> out_uid
        AND uid = ANY(in_uids);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately, there are problems - please run the 2 commands to see them:

```
test=> SELECT out_uid FROM merge_users(ARRAY[1,2]);
 out_uid 
---------
       1
(1 row)

test=> SELECT out_uid FROM merge_users(ARRAY[1,2,3,4]);
ERROR:  new row for relation "reviews" violates check constraint "reviews_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1, User 4 says: 3 is ugly).
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO reviews (
                uid,
                author,
                review
        ) SELECT
                uid,
                out_uid,        -- change to out_uid
                review
        FROM reviews
        WHERE author <> out_uid
        AND author = ANY(in_uids)
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
PL/pgSQL function merge_users(integer[]) line 38 at SQL statement
```

So deleting self-reviews seems not to work, please help.

Also I wonder if there is a better way to merge the `reviews` records, than my trick with `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

For your convenience I have created an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f37e/2).

Also I have asked this question at the very helpful [pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAADeyWitodP-9tWKK7k9qTagRfrYmfJcpOainBZ-033W4H9TzQ%40mail.gmail.com) mailing list.

Comment: The second `CREATE TABLE` statement needs to have `REFERENCES users` succeeded by `( uid )`.

Comment: I have omitted `( uid )` because the column has same name.

Comment: Ah - thank you.  I was unaware of that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would approach this by:

- Deleting any self reviews based on the combined user ids.
- Combining the rest together.

I think it is the first part that is failing.  Try this `delete`:

```
DELETE FROM reviews
WHERE uid = ANY(in_uids) AND author = ANY(in_uids);
```

That is, any combination of the old `uids` is a problem.  I'm not sure if `in_uids` contains *all* equivalent uids, but the idea is that the entire equivalent class is used for this purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't your suggestion nuke **all** reviews? I am trying to keep as many as possible while merging.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber . . . You need to nuke all reviews that are between *any* members of the equivalence class.  That is what your `check` constraint already does.